# Ffmpeg only receives a piece of information from the pipe

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, pipe, named-pipes

First of all - my english is not very good, i`m sorry for that.

I use ffmpeg from c# to convert images to video. To interact with ffmpeg, I use pipes.

```
public async Task<byte[]> ExecuteCommand(
        string arguments,
        Action<NamedPipeServerStream> sendDataUsingPipe)
    {
        var inStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            "from_ffmpeg",
            PipeDirection.In,
            1,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
            PipeBufferSize,
            PipeBufferSize);

        var outStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(
            "to_ffmpeg",
            PipeDirection.Out,
            1,
            PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
            PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
            PipeBufferSize,
            PipeBufferSize);

        var waitInConnectionTask = inStream.WaitForConnectionAsync();
        var waitOutConnectionTask = outStream.WaitForConnectionAsync();

        byte[] byteData;

        using (inStream)
        using (outStream)
        using (var inStreamReader = new StreamReader(inStream))
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                FileName = PathToFfmpeg,
                Arguments = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            process.Start();

            await waitOutConnectionTask;

            sendDataUsingPipe.Invoke(outStream);

            outStream.Disconnect();
            outStream.Close();

            await waitInConnectionTask;

            var logTask = Task.Run(() => process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
            var dataBuf = ReadAll(inStream);

            var shouldBeEmpty = inStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shouldBeEmpty))
                throw new Exception();

            var processExitTask = Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit());
            await Task.WhenAny(logTask, processExitTask);
            var log = logTask.Result;

            byteData = dataBuf;

            process.Close();
            inStream.Disconnect();
            inStream.Close();
        }

        return byteData;
    }
```

Action "sendDataUsingPipe" looks like

```
Action<NamedPipeServerStream> sendDataUsingPipe = stream =>
        {
            foreach (var imageBytes in data)
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes)))
                {
                    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        };
```

When I send 10/20/30 images (regardless of the size) ffmpeg processes everything. 
When I needed to transfer 600/700 / .. images, then in the ffmpeg log I see that it only received 189-192, and in the video there are also only 189-192 images.
There are no errors in the logs or exceptions in the code.

What could be the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: Do you ever get anything out of `logTask.Result;` ?

Comment: @GregHNZ Yes, always.